# Is this tiret cadratin being used correctly?

Tags: grammaire, ponctuation

I am writing a French haiku, and would like to know whether the em-dash, or the *tiret cadratin*, is being used correctly:

> La dent de lait : chez

> des cerisiers en fleurs et

> puis — un vent d’or.

I put the tiret cadratin in there for a dramatic pause, if that is useful information.

Comment: I am not an expert, but based on wikipedia (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiret#Tiret_long), it does not seem to be one of its usage.

Comment: Shouldn't it be *des cerisiers en fleur*?

Comment: @jlliagre Thank you for catching that, but is _fleur_  supposed to be _fleurs_ since the cerisiers are plural?

Comment: Good point. Both the singular and the plural are grammatically possible but since there is just one kind of flowers (only cherry tree flowers), the recommendation is to keep the singular. You might want to ask this as a separate question to give a better visibility to it.

Comment: And by the way, if you are a native French (or not), you can use French here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Un vent d'or* is part of the sentence. It can't be removed so is not a *proposition incise* which would have been a use case for a *tiret cadratin*.

To mark a pause, *points de suspensions* (ellipsis) are commonly used:

> puis… un vent d'or.